# How to join fetch associated child relation

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

i have the following constellation:

```
public final class ApplicationUser {

private final @Id
@Wither
long applicationUserId;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 4, max = 20)
private final
String login;

@NotNull
@Email
private final
String eMail; 

@Wither
private Set<Privilege> privileges;
}
```

Now i want to query one `ApplicationUser` by its `login` which is done by a simple sql `Query`.
**My question now:**
Is there any spring-data-jdbc related thing to jpa´s join fetch so that i can fetch the associated `Set<Privilege> privileges` in one declared query?
Or do i have to fire another query like so:

1. query `ApplicationUser` by its login
2. query `Privilege` by its foreign key `applicationuser`

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55965004/66686) describes the default way to do this. If you want to avoid the extra select you could use a statement that contains the join and use a `ResultSetExtractor` to construct your entities.

**Pro**: More efficient at runtime.

**Con**: More work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I should have waited with my question, because i´ve just found an answer myself.
So here is my answer:
Just type this sql query onto your repository function:

`@Query("select a.applicationuserid, a.email, a.login, p from applicationuser a left outer join privilege p on a.applicationuserid = p.applicationuser where lower(a.login) = lower(:login)")`

In the corresponding logs there has been fired a second sql query to fetch the privilegs.